# order by date from multiple left joins

Tags: mysql

I have the following issue. I've got 3 tables, 1 with invoices, 1 with sending records of the invoices and 1 with payment records of the invoices.

An invoice can only be paid when an invoice is send. Every payment or sending has a relation based on the column invoice_id.

So what I want is a list limited on 5 invoices which is sorted on the latest action (sending or payment). So if the last sending (based on date_time) of an invoice is newer then the last payment (based on date_time) that invoices must be on top of the list and vice verse.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(DATE) 
             FROM (SELECT DATE
                     FROM PAYMENTS P
                    WHERE P.INVOICE_ID = IN.INVOICE_ID
                    UNION 
                   SELECT DATE
                     FROM SENDS S
                    WHERE S.INVOICE_ID = IN.INVOICE_ID) SUB) MAX_DATE,
       IN.* 
  FROM INVOICE IN
 ORDER BY 1 DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

**Update:**

The SQL above doesn't work because the table invoice can't be accessed inside a second level of sub-select.

Try this select:

```
SELECT V.* 
  FROM verkoopfacturen AS V 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoice_id, 
                     MAX(datum) as max_date
               FROM (SELECT P.invoice_id,
                            P.date AS datum 
                        FROM invoice_payments AS P 
                       UNION 
                      SELECT S.file_id,
                             S.datum AS datum 
                        FROM email AS S) SUB
               GROUP BY SUB.invoice_id) SUB2 on V.Verkoopfact_InfId = SUB2.invoice_id
  ORDER BY SUB2.MAX_DATE DESC 
  LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer but i can't make it work. First of all I get an error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Try adding the alias to the first subselect of the first column, i updated the answer putting a `SUB` as alias.

Comment: I tried this: SELECT 
(
 SELECT MAX(datum)
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT P.date AS datum
        FROM invoice_payments AS P
        WHERE P.invoice_id = V.Verkoopfact_InfId
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT S.datum AS datum
        FROM email AS S
        WHERE S.file_id = V.Verkoopfact_InfId
 ) 
    SUB
) 
MAX_DATE, V.* 
FROM verkoopfacturen AS V 
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 5 But i get an error:  Unknown column 'V.Verkoopfact_InfId' in 'where clause' Strange because I know for sure that the column exist.

Comment: Updated the answer, give it a try.